# Changing permissions on Windows for FTP via XAMPP

Tags: ftp, xampp

I am developing a rather basic CMS locally and can not ftp due to permissions problems. I have FileZilla FTP *server* running in XAMPP and can connect without problems but receive error "550 Permission Denied" when my code tries to upload via ftp.

I tried changing permissions via my FileZilla FTP *client* but without success (presumably because it is windows- error: "504 Command not implemented for that parameter"). I also tried going to the target folder's properties --> security --> permissions and checking "full" for the user XAMPP is running under.

So how do I setup the permissions to allow my CMS to use ftp in XAMPP?

Answer (score 5):

Finally figured it out. For anyone else who has this problem, there is no need to set permissions in Windows. Instead, on the FileZilla FTP server admin interface select edit --> users --> shared folders and check 'write'.

Comment: Where is this? I can not find this Edit Users Shared Folders

Comment: Open the Admin FileZilla-Interface with XAMPP Control and then you can follow this path

Comment: what if it doesn't help?

Answer (score 0):

For a fix of this make sure that the root folder is allowed to write and pass rights permission. had this same issue for a script to run on local web xampp server windows xp..  just change the root file attributes to 755 then try it if that don't work try 777. should work now... hope this works for you... as it did me.

If that does not work go to your htdocs folder in your xampp directory then right click it and check properties .. if read only is ticked .. untick it and apply to all sub folders and files

Answer (score 0):

You're behind firewall? Try to allow FileZilla server program in Firewall.